# how to show views & layout with a class that extends Application

Tags: android

I managed to show a toast every time my app start up using the code below:

```
<application
        android:name=".Startup"
...
```

```
public class Startup extends Application {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Toast.makeText(this, "Startup", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Activity a = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
        a.setContentView(R.layout.startup_layout);

    }
}
```

but I also want to show some views during app start up and I didn't find any materials on how to do this? I add this layout(to show some views) and bind it to this class but the app crashed with a `java.lang.ClassCastException`

the layout bind to the class:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="try" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

So my questions are:
1. How to show views or layout with this class? 
2. How to show and control some views in other activities using this class?

I am still learning android and not sure how to do it :(

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Application class is not the class for showing views, instead in this class you can initialize some libraries, dependency injection frameworks etc. For showing screens you should create Activity or Fragment

You should remove this code from the Application class:

```java
Activity a = (Activity) getApplicationContext();
a.setContentView(R.layout.startup_layout);
```

In AndroidManifest.xml file you should have starting Activity defined, and in Activity you should set the content view:

AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example">
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.MainActivity"> // package name where you have MainActivity
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.startup_layout)
    }

}
```

Comment: Also the best you can do to start your journey with Android:
1. Install Android Studio
2. Go to File -> New -> New Project
3. Choose project from template with Basic Activity for example to check how the project is configured

Comment: Oh I forgot to mentioned I did initialize the name in manifest, I will edit the question, so there is no way to show a button view in class? or could I run a function from mainactivity in this class?

Comment: Application is not a place where you put UI, Activity is